# MySQL backup only innodb tables

Tags: backup, innodb, mysql

How, can I backup only the Innodb tables.

I'm looking for command line solution.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291641/how-to-selectively-dump-all-innodb-tables-in-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqlbackup utility isn't available in Community installation !

I'll try **msqldump**.

**First** I list all the InnoDB tables, **then** I execute the msqldump on each of these tables (loop).

Answer (score 2):

if you are using [mysqlbackup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.7/en/installing.html) , you can do it using `--only-innodb` option

```
 mysqlbackup --defaults-file=/home/pekka/.my.cnf --only-innodb backup
```

look on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.7/en/only-innodb-usage.html